# Overriding errors.Is() not working with custom errors

Tags: go

I am trying to create a custom error in Go such that I can create new instances of that error with a custom message, and then handle that specific type of error. However, when I try to do this, then my overridden `errors.Is()` is not being executed. Here is my code:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "errors"
)

type Error struct {
        Message string
        Code int
}

func (e *Error) Error() string {
        return e.Message
}

func (e Error) Is(target Error) bool {
        // This is never printed - this method never excutes for some reason
        fmt.Println("compared!")
        return e.Code == target.Code
}

var NotFoundError *Error = &Error{Code: 404, Message: "The page was not found"}

func NewError(errorType *Error, message string) error {
        rc := *errorType
        rc.Message = message

        return &rc
}

func FetchImage() error {
        return NewError(NotFoundError, "That image is gone")
}

func main() {
        err := FetchImage()

        // Returns false
        fmt.Println(errors.Is(err, NotFoundError))
}
```

In this case, the call to `errors.Is()` returns false. However, even though I have supplied my own Is() function, that function is not being called at all. That is, the string `"compared!"` is never printed.

Why isn't my Is() function working as desired?

Comment: Read the section about method sets in the Spec.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
type Error struct {
        Message string
        Code int
}

func (e *Error) Error() string {
        return e.Message
}

func (e *Error) Is(tgt error) bool {
        // This is never printed - this method never excutes for some reason
        fmt.Println("compared!")
        target, ok := tgt.(*Error)
        if !ok{
          return false
        }
        return e.Code == target.Code
}
```

Your Error struct does not implement `Is` method correctly, the parameter should be `error` not `Error`.

See in action:

https://play.golang.org/p/vRQndE9ZRuH

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
)

type Error struct {
        Message string
        Code int
}

func (e *Error) Error() string {
        return e.Message
}

func (e *Error) Is(target Error) bool {
        // This is now printed
        fmt.Println("compared!")
        return e.Code == target.Code
}

var NotFoundError Error = Error{Code: 404, Message: "The page was not found"}

func NewError(errorType Error, message string) Error {
        rc := errorType
        rc.Message = message

        return rc
}

func FetchImage() Error {
        return NewError(NotFoundError, "That image is gone")
}

func main() {
        err := FetchImage()

        // Now it returns true
        fmt.Println(err.Is(NotFoundError))
}
```